# How to validate a number of wtform fields all together to satisfy a condition

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a form with a couple of fields in it. The class that hold the form looks like

```
class TestForm(Form):
      some_stuff_1 = IntegerField('Cool Bucket', description="Cool bucket",default=0,validators[validators.Optional(),validators.NumberRange(0, 100)])
      some_stuff_2 = IntegerField('Boring Bucket', description="Boring bucket",default=0,validators[validators.Optional(),validators.NumberRange(0, 100)])
      some_stuff_3 = IntegerField('Funny Bucket', description="Funny bucket",default=0,validators[validators.Optional(),validators.NumberRange(0, 100)])
      some_stuff_4 = IntegerField('Amazing Bucket', description="Amazing bucket",default=0,validators[validators.Optional(),validators.NumberRange(0, 100)])
```

The above works fine. But now i have a extra condition where i want to validate that the user should not enter all `0` for all 4 fields. So basically i am looking for a custome validation here which should say flash me a message if the user entered 0 on all four fields. I have taken the look at flask wtforms custom validation, but it just applies to a one field at a time, here i am trying to apply the validation to a couple of fields.

Can someone guide me how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to connect into the validation hook and write your own test.

```
class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    val1 = IntegerField('Cool Bucket', description="Cool bucket",default=0,validators[validators.Optional(),validators.NumberRange(0, 100)])
    val2 = IntegerField('Cool Bucket', description="Cool bucket",default=0,validators[validators.Optional(),validators.NumberRange(0, 100)])

    def validate(self):
        rv = FlaskForm.validate(self)
        if not rv:
            return False

        test = (self.val1.data == 0) and (self.val2.data == 0)
        if test:
            self.val1.errors.append('Val1 and 2 cannot be 0')
            return False

        return True
```